# How to get substring in between certain tokens?

Tags: python, string

Say I have file that contains strings like `'STARTabcdEND'`, how should I extract all strings found between `'START'` and `'END'` in the file, in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re

s = 'STARTabcdENDefSTARTghiEND'
a = 'START'
b = 'END'
out = re.findall(a+'(.+?)'+b, s)
# out: ['abcd', 'ghi']
```

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry for not being clear the first time.

Comment: In general `a,b = map(re.escape, [a,b])` might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here this would be one way to do it

```
s = 'STARTabcdEND'
s.partition('START')[2].rpartition('END')[0]
```